# Observer to notify new maximum values in ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, observer-pattern

I'm working on a Tabletop RPG Character Creator with Java that's got to implement Design Patterns, but I can't seem to get Observer right.

This is what my program does.

1. On startup, it loads all characters already created from a folder and saves them on an Arraylist
2. A menu gives the user an option to roll stats for new characters and saves them on the Arraylist and as a file on the Characters Folder

[image: Picture of my program's Class Diagram]

**I want my observer to observe on the ArrayList and notify me when a new character with a new highest stat is created (strength, dexterity, etc)**

Please, if something's not clear with my question let me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should store the List of Characters in a specific class and make this class extend an `Observable` class (JDK class or your own if you want to have a more specific semantic ).
If you create your own classes you could have two classes :
`NewHighestCharacterObservable` and `NewHighestCharacterObserver`.

The `NewHighestCharacterObservable` class provides at least these two methods to implement the pattern :

- a method to add a `NewHighestCharacterObserver` to it.
  For example `addObserver(NewHighestCharacterObserver)`.
- a method to notify `NewHighestCharacterObserver`s of a change.
  For example `notifyObservers(Character newCharacterWithHigherStat)`.
  It is `notifyObservers()` and not `notifyObserver()` to make it easy to change if later multiple observers need to observe this observable.

Then, to be notified, make your GUI an observable by implementing the `NewHighestCharacterObserver` interface that provides a method to be updated :

- onNewHighestCharacter(Character c)

This is the method that is invoked by `notifyObservers()`.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try to implement this!